# Native or framework programming for my app? And if framework, which one?

Tags: android, ios, frameworks

I want to develop application for Android and iOS.
It will be simple application with some data of users and some achievement animations.
It will comunicate with our servers, where will be used REST as backend.
I need the application to be secured. There will be stored very sensitive data.
I think application won't need much performance.
I'm going to be project leader, so I have to find programmer. So if I use framework, then the programming language will have to be in good performance/price ratio.

Comment: If you're not doing anything with hardware, and want an app that you could build in a web page, there are cross-platform frameworks such as PhoneGap. You have to add value though because Apple doesn't approve apps that are just converted from a web page.

Comment: And is it secure? Is it able to comunicate with our servers through JSON?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's difficult to answer your question due to lack of information, but I have gained some experience regarding this topic from the past year.

The choice of your frameworks depends on time/cost, resources and know-how. I suppose your question is about whether to use a webframe including webprogramming, or native iOS and Android implementation.

The big advantages of using a Webframe are:

- Can easily be included on both platforms Only has to be implemented
  once (with a view platform specific adaptions e.g. access to camera
  etc.)
- No additional know-how is required (just JavaScript and HTML)
- The implementation is easy and development fast Subsequently the development time is reduced

The disadvantages are:

- Webframes are slow
- If there are animations like transitions it could be laggy
- User triggered events could also be delayed. (just a few milliseconds, but it could be very annoying.
- This could conclude in a total useless app, because the userexperience is very bad.

If you want a throughout solid app which offers a flawless userexperience I highly recommend a native implementation. But you have to consider, this affords experienced Android and iOS programmer, and is associated with more development time and subsequenlty more costs.

I recommend to implement a simple prototype which includes the animations and the main features. If the userexperience is good then go for it.